# Case statement that has to check through another table

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql

I have the table t1:

```
pers_key  code1  code2
       1     AA     BB
       2     AA     CC
       3     AA     DD
       4     BB     CC
       5     BB     DD
       6     CC     DD
```

And another table t2:

```
code  ind_A  ind_B  ind_C
  AA      1      0      0
  BB      0      1      0
  CC      0      0      1
  DD      1      0      1
```

I want to join these tables together so that for each record in t1, we add columns ind_A, ind_B, ind_C and set them to 1 if the respective code specifies it. For example, this would be my ideal output table:

```
pers_key  code1  code2  ind_A  ind_B  ind_C
       1     AA     BB      1      1      0
       2     AA     CC      1      0      1
       3     AA     DD      1      0      1
       4     BB     CC      0      1      1 
       5     BB     DD      1      1      1
       6     CC     DD      1      0      1
```

So for each t1 record, we are setting the inds to 1 if its code1 OR code2 has the inds as 1 in the other table t2. What would be the best way to achieve this result? Keep in mind this is just a sample to get the idea/method, in my actual data there are hundreds of different code values. I am using HIVE/hiveQl version 0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive doesn't support subqueries in the `SELECT` clause.  But, you can do this using joins:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2a.ind_A = 1 or t2b.ind_A = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ind_A,
       (case when t2a.ind_B = 1 or t2b.ind_B = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ind_B,
       (case when t2a.ind_C = 1 or t2b.ind_C = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ind_C
from t1 left join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.code1 = t2a.code left join
     t2 t2b
     on t1.code2 = t2b.code;
```

Note:  this should work even for codes that don't match t2